# Different enterprise signed apps on same iOS device

Tags: ios, code-signing, enterprise

Company A has an Apple Enterprise Developer account and distributes "in-house" iOS applications signed with its account key. Likewise, Company B does the same with its own in-house apps.

Is it possible to install a Company A enterprise-signed app *and* a Company B enterprise-signed app on the *same* iOS device? Or are iOS devices restricted to apps from at most one Enterprise Developer? Can someone point to Apple documentation that addresses this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes, it's possible.** Apps can be installed from multiple enterprise locations on the same device. Whilst I haven't been able to find a citable source, I have personal experience as I have apps from an enterprise organisation installed on my device as well as the SE iOS beta app which is distributed through enterprise.

Comment: Can also say that I personally used signed apps from multiple enterprise sources on my iPhone at the same time without issue. Each one issues me a provisioning profile, viewable in `Settings > General > Profiles`, for their applications. They don't conflict.